measure theory about completeness of measure
Let ($X,\mathcal A$) be a measurable space, and let $\mu$ be a measure on ($X,\mathcal A$) . The  completion of $\mathcal A$ under $\mu$  is the collection of subsets $A$ of $X$ for which there are sets $E$ and $F$ in $\mathcal A $ such that
\begin{equation}
E \subset A \subset F\\\\
\mu(E-F)＝0
\end{equation}
If  $B$ is  a subset of $A$ that belongs to $\mathcal A$ ,then
\begin{equation}
 \mu(B)\leq \mu(E)＝ \mu(F)
\end{equation}
My question is:
Why does the following expression hold?
\begin{equation}
\mu(E)＝\sup \{\mu(B):B\in\mathcal A \, \text{ and } B\subset A\}
\end{equation}
Do I need to use the definition of the supremum to prove the following conclusion？
i.e for every $\epsilon ＞0$，there exists a subset $B$ of $A$ that belongs to $\mathcal A$ such that
$
\mu(B)＞\mu(E)-\epsilon$？
How can I find such a  subset？
